# regular expression to get a particular string from a data

Tags: regex, node.js

I have following data

```
List of devices attached
192.168.56.101:5555    device product:vbox86p model:Samsung_Galaxy_Note_2___4_3___API_18___720x1280 device:vbox86p
192.168.56.102:5555    device product:vbox86tp model:Google_Nexus_7___4_3___API_18___800x1280 device:vbox86tp
```

from this data i want to search S`amsung_Galaxy_Note_`2 and retunn its corresponding `192.168.56.102:5555`

how it is possbile using regular expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the simplest, you can use this in multi-line mode:

```
^(\S+).*Samsung_Galaxy_Note_2
```

and retrieve the match from Group 1. In [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/fS8mF0/2), see the group capture in the **right pane**.

In JS:

```
var myregex = /^(\S+).*Samsung_Galaxy_Note_2/m;
var matchArray = myregex.exec(yourString);
if (matchArray != null) {
    thematch = matchArray[0];
}
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `(\S+)` captures to Group 1 any chars that are not white-space chars
- `.*` matches any chars
- `Samsung_Galaxy_Note_2` matches literal chars

Comment: one thing also if i assigned the word var device =Samsung_Galaxy_Note_2 then  can i use ^\S+(?=.*?+device+)

Comment: sorry it is not working tried code ` var device = 'Samsung_Galaxy_Note_2';
  //var device = 'Google_Nexus_7' 
  
  var myregex = new RegExp("^(\S+).*" + device, 'm')
  var matchArray = myregex.exec(data);
  if (matchArray != null) {
  thematch = matchArray[0];
  console.log(thematch)
  }`           Am getting undefined while ouputing thematch

Comment: You mean the dynamically generated regex works for one but not the other? That doesn't sound right. In your tests, did you generate one regex for the Samsung, and one regex for the Google? And no typos?

Comment: dont know.....it is also not working..if putting device name directly it is working man!!!!but i need to put device itself...:-(

Comment: hi it worked when i use like this `var myregex = new RegExp( '^(\\S+).*' + device, 'm')`

Comment: Arrr... YES! Well done, you cracked it! Awesome, see you next time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Without any **capturing groups** and the one through *positive lookahead*,

```
^\S+(?=.*?Samsung_Galaxy_Note_2)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bB9hN3/4)